# SQL query to transform table

Tags: sql, database, excel, sap-ase

I got a problem transforming a table that looks like this

```
city    | distributor | phno
---------------------------------
new york   xxx           12345

new york   yyy           12312

new york   zzz           12313

london     aaa           12315

london     bbb           11111

hong konk  ccc           12311
```

into

```
city    | distributor1 | phno1 | distributor2 | phno2 | distributor3 | phno3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
new york   xxx           12345      yyy         12312     zzz           12313

london     aaa           12315      bbb         11111     0             0             

hong konk  ccc           12311       0            0       0             0
```

- given that any city does not more and 3 distributers

I have tried the self join but I get duplicate records, please advise.

**Let me know if this be done in excel ??** as this for reporting purpose only

Comment: Do you need to achieve it using SQL? There are many reporting tools like Crystal and reporting services (and more...) that do the job for you!

Comment: i dont have those tools , the best i have is excel !! but i look at it as more of challenging sql guery :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can PIVOT tables in SQL as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's valid in Sybase SQL, still I would start with something like this in other SQL servers:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT city FROM table GROUP BY city) AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 distributor AS distributor1, phno AS phno1 
    FROM table c1 WHERE c1.city = c.city 
    ORDER BY distributor ASC) AS c1
    ON true
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 2 distributor AS distributor2, phno AS phno2 
    FROM table c2 WHERE c2.city = c.city 
    ORDER BY distributor ASC) AS c2
    ON distributor1 != distributor2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 3 distributor AS distributor3, phno AS phno3 
    FROM table c3 WHERE c3.city = c.city 
    ORDER BY distributor ASC) AS c3
    ON distributor1 != distributor3 AND distributor2 != distributor3
```

Comment: Sybase has `TOP`, not `LIMIT` but I'm not sure if it can be used in subqueries.

Comment: Limit is not valid for Sybase and SQL Server. Using TOP and OVER ROWS instead

Comment: i dont get this portion ORDER BY distributor ASC, phno ASC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1 , could you plz explain

Comment: The idea is to sort the results in strict order so database engine doesn't fetch equal rows by accident.

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of transformation is best done in a report writer, not in the database.

Comment: you mean like in excel ? is this possible ?

Comment: I agree: this is probably better done using an Excel Pivot table

Comment: I don't usually think of Excel as a report writer, but it might work. I was thinking about things like Crystal Reports, Microsoft Access (best report writer I've used in years), and ReportBuilder.